# Google Autocomplete Place HTML5 Pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, html, autocomplete

Google Autocomplete Places is a powerful tool to autocomplete postal address. Unfortunately, it doesn't prevent people from entering a wrong format address.
Thus, I would like to add an HTML5 pattern to disable wrong French format address.

The problem is that it must be written in regex...
My condition is: to be ended with "France" (my target are French users). I've tried with :

```
<input id="autocomplete" name="adresse2" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Adresse (ex: 22 rue de la Paix, Paris, France)" required pattern="#France$#">
```

but it block any good/bad address.

JSFiddle (not working properly as the body must be "onload"): http://jsfiddle.net/dzhzf5ff/
French Google format address exemple: *24 rue des Peupliers, Paris, France*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern must be written without delimiters and anchors, it is implicitly anchored, consequence, you must describe the string form begining to end. So basically you must write this:

```
pattern=".*France"
```